# Override a private method in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I understand that the private method cannot be override, but here is my question.

`A_CLASS_FROM_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARY_THAT_I_CANNOT_MODIFY` is from 3rd party library that I cannot modify:

```
open class A_CLASS_FROM_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARY_THAT_I_CANNOT_MODIFY {
    private fun print() {
        println("A")
    }
    
    open public fun run() {
        // A lot of code here
        // A lot of code here
        // A lot of code here
        
        print()
        
        // A lot of code here
        // A lot of code here
        // A lot of code here
    }
}
```

The only thing I want to change is the `print()` method in it. Is there any better way than override the entire `run()` method, and copy & paste all of the code from supper class, in order to override the private `print()` method? For example,

```
class B : A_CLASS_FROM_3RD_PARTIES_THAT_I_CANNOT_MODIFY() {
    private fun print() {
        println("B")
    }
    
    // Copy & paste the whole run() method from supper class
    override public fun run() {
        // A lot of code here
        // A lot of code here
        // A lot of code here
        
        print()
        
        // A lot of code here
        // A lot of code here
        // A lot of code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not making `print` `protected`?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle it's from some libraries that I cannot modify.

Comment: Then, no, there is no other option.

Comment: private methods are meant to be not overridable.

Comment: Addendum: from the perspective of a user of that library you shouldn't even know or care how the method `run` is implemented.

Comment: Addendum 2: is that lib on github? Then make that change and file a *pull request*.

Comment: If the `print` method is not called from within any other method of class `A` your only option is to wrap it in another class and use that to access the features of class `A` excluding the `print` method.  Of course this depends on how class `A` is used by the library, and if you need to create your wrapping class to confirm to the same "interface" as class `A`

Comment: @Gavin How do you "wrap it in another class and use that to access the features of class A excluding the print"?

Comment: As the others have already pointed out, private methods can not be overridden. However, if you want to define a function in a class without having to create a new class, you could use extension functions, i.e., `fun A.customPrint() { }`

Comment: I vote for doing the pull request. Feels like a design error to have an open function call a private one.

Comment: @iForests actually, looking at your original example, I dont think you can.  I think your only options are if its an open source project, engage with with the project or get low level and make use of reflection and or byte code weaving.  Or select a different library.

Comment: OK, I am going to file a pull request. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to override private methods, neither in Kotlin nor in Java.